# Within a list of dicts, convert in-place all datetime objects to strings?

Tags: python, json, datetime

I want to convert all datetime objects to strings for JSON file output purposes. I am given a data_list and I use an encoder and output as such:

```
class DateTimeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, (datetime.datetime, datetime.date, datetime.time)):
            return obj.isoformat()
        elif isinstance(obj, datetime.timedelta):
            return (datetime.datetime.min + obj).time().isoformat()
    
        return super(DateTimeEncoder, self).default(obj)

def write_to_file(data_list):
    encoder = datetime_encoder.DateTimeEncoder()
    for record in data_list:
        encoder.encode(record)
    with open('data.json', 'w') as fout:
        json.dumps(data_list, fout)
```

Example data_list:

```
[
    {
        'field1': 'foo', 
        'field2': 'fang', 
        'fielda': 0, 
        'fieldb': 2020-10-10 12:00:00
    }, 
    {
        'field1': 'ab', 
        'field2': 'cd', 
        'fielda': 1, 
        'fieldb': 2020-10-10 12:00:00
    },
    ...
]
```

The problem is, this encoder does not encode in-place, and I am also iterating through every single record which is not scalable if data_list is particularly big. I am accepting the data through psycopg2, so maybe I can perform the encoding on whatever data is incoming instead of parsing after the fact?

Comment: Why not fetching the data from Postgres as string or unix timestamp directly ?

Comment: `fieldb` is a string?

Comment: @orlevii No, sorry I should have been more explicit in showing those are datetime objects

Comment: Do you know, in advance, the keys in each dictionary that have `datetime` values? That's the only way to avoid iterating every single record.

Comment: @martineau Unfortunately no

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Can that be done using psycopg2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```py
def v(i):
    if isinstance(i, (datetime.datetime, datetime.date, datetime.time)):
        return i.isoformat()
    elif isinstance(i, datetime.timedelta):
        return (datetime.datetime.min + i).time().isoformat()

    return i

res = json.dumps(data,
                 default=v)
```

EDIT: Saving to a file can be done with:

```py
with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, default=v)
```

Comment: What am I to do with res? I need to output my data_list into a JSON file (Hence json.dump(data_list, fout))

Comment: It's basically the same. Editing my answer

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you could just change the data type while selecting and/or let postgres create the JSON for you.
Just showing 3 options how to select without any need to convert the data in Python:

```
import datetime as dt 
import psycopg2
import json

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=mf port=5959 host=localhost user=mf_usr")
cur = conn.cursor()


sql = """CREATE TEMP TABLE test(num int, creation date)"""
cur.execute(sql)

# insert some dummy data
for num in range(5):
    vals = (num, dt.date.today())
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (num, creation) VALUES (%s, %s)", vals)

# Regular select, psycopg2 uses datetime
cur.execute("SELECT * from test")
print(cur.fetchall())

# Select date column as text:
cur.execute("SELECT num, creation::text from test")
print(json.dumps(cur.fetchall()))

# Postgres select directly as JSON output:
cur.execute("SELECT row_to_json(test) from test")
print(json.dumps(cur.fetchall()))

# Select date column as unix timestamp:
cur.execute("SELECT num, extract(epoch from creation) from test")
print(json.dumps(cur.fetchall()))
```

Output:

```
[(0, datetime.date(2020, 9, 18)), (1, datetime.date(2020, 9, 18)), (2, datetime.date(2020, 9, 18)), (3, datetime.date(2020, 9, 18)), (4, datetime.date(2020, 9, 18))]
[[0, "2020-09-18"], [1, "2020-09-18"], [2, "2020-09-18"], [3, "2020-09-18"], [4, "2020-09-18"]]
[[{"num": 0, "creation": "2020-09-18"}], [{"num": 1, "creation": "2020-09-18"}], [{"num": 2, "creation": "2020-09-18"}], [{"num": 3, "creation": "2020-09-18"}], [{"num": 4, "creation": "2020-09-18"}]]
[[0, 1600387200.0], [1, 1600387200.0], [2, 1600387200.0], [3, 1600387200.0], [4, 1600387200.0]]
```